# How do I sort entries by two variables?

Tags: templating, entries, sorting

Currently I am sorting the entries by an ID:

```
{% for gallery in craft.entries.section('Gallery').order('available desc').limit(none) %}
```

but I would like to show the latest entries on top, currently it shows available first but latest entries ones go to the bottom. How can I mix the above code with something like this?

```
.order('postDate desc') %}
```

Comment: At the risk of asking a stupid question, have you tried just chaining them? `.order('this asc').order('that desc').limit(10)`. Just a hunch, but I can't test it out right now.

Comment: I did... it only recognizes the last .order :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to order by multiple columns that include custom fields, first make sure you're at least on [Craft 2.4.2684](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2684), then you'll be able to use this syntax:

```
{% for gallery in craft.entries.section('Gallery').order('postDate desc, available desc').limit(null) %}
```

Also note that that you should be using `limit(null)` instead of `limit(none)` if you want to result all results.

Comment: For some reason the syntax you showed gives me an error `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'available' in 'order clause'`, but wen reversing the order it worked as expected :) `.order('available desc, postDate desc')`

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'available' in 'order clause'`

Comment: You have a custom field with an `available` handle in the field layout of your `Gallery` section?

Comment: Yes, I do have a custom field with a handle available